# How to do a safe "SELECT FOR UPDATE" with a WHERE condition over multiple tables on a DB2?

Tags: db2, database-deadlocks

#### Problem

On a DB2 (version 9.5) the SQL statement

```
SELECT o.Id FROM Table1 o, Table2 x WHERE [...] FOR UPDATE WITH RR
```

gives me the error message `SQLSTATE=42829` (The FOR UPDATE clause is not allowed because the table specified by the cursor cannot be modified).

#### Additional info

I need to specify `WITH RR`, because I'm running on isolation level `READ_COMMITTED`, but I need my query to block while there is another process running the same query.

#### Solution so far...

If I instead query like this:

```
SELECT t.Id FROM Table t WHERE t.Id IN (
    SELECT o.Id FROM Table1 o, Table2 x WHERE [...]
) FOR UPDATE WITH RR
```

everything works fine.

#### New problem

But now I occasionally get deadlock exceptions when multiple processes perform this query simultaneously.

#### Question

Is there a way to formulate the `FOR UPDATE` query without introducing a place where a deadlock can occur?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, for having isolation level `READ_COMMITTED` you do not need to specify `WITH RR`, because this results in the isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`. To specify `WITH RS` (Read Stability) is enough.

To propagate the `FOR UPDATE WITH RS` to the inner select you have to specify additionally `USE AND KEEP UPDATE LOCKS`.

So the complete statement looks like this:

```
SELECT t.Id FROM Table t WHERE t.Id IN (
    SELECT o.Id FROM Table1 o, Table2 x WHERE [...]
) FOR UPDATE WITH RS USE AND KEEP UPDATE LOCKS
```

I made some tests on a DB2 via JDBC and it worked without deadlocks.